# OpenCL on ATI Radeon HD 4650

Tags: graphics, gpu, opencl

From some time I have had an [Radeon HD 4650 AGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_4000_Series#Radeon_HD_4600) graphic card. I wanted to start [mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_protocol#Bitcoin_mining) on my GPU, as it brings more [BTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin), but miners are not able to find my card.

I've checked it with [GPU Caps Viewer](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/), and it shows that it does not support OpenCL.
Is it true? If it normally supports it, how can I make it work?

Comment: Have you made sure you have the latest graphics drivers?

Comment: Yes, I have the newest drivers possible.
@magicandre1981 Is there a possibility to get some kind of modded drivers that would make OpenCL work on 4650 ?

Comment: @CamIce I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Well, thank you, then, my friend :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happen to own both HD 4650 and 4670 AGP cards and have already verified that they do indeed support OpenCL 1.0 at least in a Windows environment (tested on Windows XP and Windows 7 32 bit).

I did notice, however, that with most Catalyst versions they are not recognized as OpenCL devices, so you might have to play around with the driver/application version. Mainly I would suggest using Catalyst version 11.9 AGP hotfix.

I've tested performance of the cards in oclhashcat benchmark and here are the results for [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) brute forcing on each cards:

- HD4650 AGP: 265.6 Mhash/s @ 600 MHz
- HD4670 AGP: 329.1 Mhash/s @ 750 MHz

One more thing to keep in mind is that for OpenCL to work you need a CPU with SSE2 or greater. On both of my AGP legacy machines I'm running [Pentium 4 prescott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4#Prescott).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortably, I have newly switched to Ubuntu, but I will surely find a way to get something out of the graphic card :)
Do you think it would work with Intel Pentium 4 Northwood? Mine CPU is pretty close "brothers" with yours, so it should work, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

According to AMD, you [need at least a Radeon HD5400](http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements-driver-compatibility/).